# Making a multi-step selection process with different outcome for each page

Tags: php, symfony

On any given page (It's used site-wide for different purposes) I'd like to call a function `getMyForm()` or something similar and this would render a several step selection process for a product. We only have this one product but it is quite a complex selection process.

If I wanted to implement this on one page only it would be fairly simple... but I'd like this selection process to be available on different pages, and it seems silly for me to recreate the form for each page used when it's only really the outcome after the selection process that will change for each.

**How would I go about achieving this:**

1. Should I have the form on it's own page anyway then link to it at the beginning of the selection process and redirect to the appropriate page after selection depending on the page the user first came from?
2. Use a service container or similar to render the form on the specific page, then use session attributes/variables to track which step the user is currently on, and refresh the current page after each selection.
3. Something completely different?

**Additional stuff:**

- I want this to be functional without javascript/jQuery, but this
  would be a nice addition in future so I don't want to rule it out if
  possible.
- The selection process is dependent on what was selected in the
  previous step, so I can't just render the whole form in step one, and
  some kind of refresh will be required.

Answer (score 0):

First, i'd say you can't completely avoid javascript your selection process, if only for triggering change event on your selectors. Having user to manually trigger page refresh through some button doesn't seem like a good idea.

But if you're so inclined, you need to create a form controller with form builder, there just check a request and render a form accordingly.

For example, if no request is supplied it renders a starting form contains only one `select` and a `submit` button, and its action is simple submit to the same page. Main page controller includes a form controller, so form controller gets a request and renders second part and so on...